# Active Admin Scopes Not working 1.0.0.pre2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using active admin with ActiveRecord scopes. However, I'm having an issue with adding the scopes.

Running ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux] and 
Rails 4.2.5.1

```
    #app/model/accounts.rb
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    searchkick


    belongs_to :program
    belongs_to :insurance
    has_many :notes
    scope :program_name, -> (program) {where(program_name: adult) }

    validates :first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone, presence: true
    validates :phone, format: { with: /\A\d{3} \d{3}-\d{4}\z/,
    message: "must be in the format 123 456-7890" }
    end
```

I want to be able to us this in app/admin/account.rb

```
#app/admin/account.rb

            ActiveAdmin.register Account do
            menu :priority => 2
            permit_params :first_name, :last_name, :return_client, :program_id, :insurance_id, :address, :phone



            index do
              column :first_name
              column :last_name
              column :address
              column :phone
              column :created_at
              column :return_client
              column :program
              column :insurance
              actions
            end
             scope :all, :default => true

             scope :adult, default: true do |accounts|
              accounts.program_name('adult')
            end
            end
```

I tired using it with and without block. I want the total count of "programs" in that scope as an end result.

Comment: Even though I have never used it, I've seen its documentation and seems that models are full managed by the framework. And "scope" word can be 
conflict by itself "scope", a filter screen.   I always avoid using frameworks or plugins, if I can do it myself

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two default scopes and the `scope :all` is unnecessary so remove it.

You have this scope which looks fine

```
scope :program_name, -> (program) {where(program_name: adult) }
```

and you say that

> I want to be able to us this in app/admin/account.rb

but you aren't actually using it. You are instead trying to use

```
scope :adult, default: true do |accounts|
  accounts.program_name('adult')
end
```

So just add it

```
scope :program_name
```

---

But your question seems to be loaded with something else you're trying to do

> I want the total count of "programs" in that scope as an end result.

And in that ^ sense, I think you may be misunderstanding how and what [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) are actually used for.